# Error handling for datepicker php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hello how do i fix this? for example, the user selects a date in the future, for example, today is oct 5, and the user inputs oct 20 then he selects for the $dateto to be in the past, sept 30 perhaps

how will i prevent the user from doing such thing?

here are my codes

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['datefrom']) && ($_GET['dateto'])){
$datefrom   = $_GET['datefrom'];
$dateto     = $_GET['dateto'];
    $qry = "SELECT sum(order_detail.quantity*order_detail.price) as chenes, orders.date 
        FROM order_detail 
        LEFT JOIN orders 
        ON order_detail.orderid=orders.serial
        WHERE date(orders.date) BETWEEN '$datefrom' AND '$dateto'";
}
else {
    $qry = "SELECT sum(order_detail.quantity*order_detail.price) as chenes, orders.date 
        FROM order_detail 
        LEFT JOIN orders 
        ON order_detail.orderid=orders.serial";
}


mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}   
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

//echo $datefrom." ";
//echo $dateto." - ";
echo "₱".number_format($row['chenes'],2);

}
?>
```

$datefrom is the past, and $dateto is in the present or still the past but not waaay past the $datefrom.

$datefrom should always be earlier than $dateto.

please help me, thank you. :)

Comment: Where is your datepicker code?

Comment: hmm. its just a basic. input type="date" @BojanPetkovski

Comment: why not compare with current date ??? if those are greater than current, obviously it's fake

Answer (score 1):

The way I've dealt with it (if I don't deal with it via JS before it gets to this point) would be:

```
// This puts both dates into a date format PHP can understand
$tmpFrom = strtotime($_GET['datefrom']);
$tmpTo = strtotimem($_GET['dateto']);

// Compare the dates, if TO is after (greater) than FROM, everything's fine.  Otherwise, Swap 'em.
$dateFrom = ($tmpTo - $tmpFrom ) > 0 ? $_GET['datefrom'] : $_GET['dateto'];
$dateTo = ($tmpTo - $tmpFrom ) > 0 ? $_GET['dateto'] :$_GET['datefrom'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with jQuery ui datepicker.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/ymcrnmm3/1/

```
$("#datefrom").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        $("#dateto").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
});
$("#dateto").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        $("#datefrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change to timestamp and subtracting each ones. Then you can compare it that is greater or not.

```
$from = strtotime($_GET['datefrom']);
$to = strtotime($_GET['dateto']);
$now = time();

$interval1 = $now - $from;
$interval2 = $now - $to;

if($now > $interval1 || $now > $interval2) {

    // do the rest 

}
```